# How to convert OGG, MP3 or WAV to MIDI?

Tags: android, mp3, wav, midi, ogg

I search all over the place and find nothing.

Is there any softwere that can help me with the task?

I need it for sound and music in our Android Game.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how `MIDI` files are all just a few kilobytes in size, while `MP3's` are a few megabytes, `WAV` even more?

`MIDI` files consist of notes and instruments. You need special sound libraries to play them. Different libraries sound different. Same file can sound really different on Windows and Android. On the other hand `MP3`, `OGG` and `WAV` all consist of waveforms (actual sound). You can convert `MIDI` to `MP3` easily.

Converting `MP3` to `MIDI` would require analysing waveforms to extract notes and instruments or doing it manually in music editors. `MIDI` also can't have vocals (except for aah insrument). You're better trying to play `MP3` or `OGG` files.